# Reset/Restart my id pk field on a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: qgis, postgis

How do I reset/restart my id primary key field on a table in PostgreSQL? I don't want to delete all the data in my table, only reset/restart my id pk counting.

This is the code I'm trying to use but it is not working:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE "CoronelFabriciano"."MV_PPI2010_LOTES_id_seq" RESTART
```

CoronelFabriciano is my schema, MV_PPI2010_LOTES is my table, id is the field I want to restart.

[image]

Comment: That might cause wierd things to happen - anything that is doing a join is now not going to uniquely match - the sequence doesn't check what values are used it just continues monotonically increasing ...

Comment: There's no joins involved with this table. If it was a shapefile I would just run an $id and reset the value for all features, but since it's in Postgis I can't do it. It doesn't work.

Comment: What do you want, reset the sequence so the NEXT value is the current max+1, or renumber the EXISTING rows from 1?

Comment: Renumber the existing rows from 1!

Comment: This answer over at SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894162/compact-or-renumber-ids-for-all-tables-and-reset-sequences-to-maxid) deals with renumbering ...

Answer (score 1):

To renumber the entire table, you would reset the sequence value to 0 (so the next call returns 1), then update the table. IF you have a unique/primary key on the column, you may have to bump the currents values first to avoid duplicates.

```sql
--reset to 1
SELECT setval(‘my_sequence_name’, 1);

--Populate the table
UPDATE my_table_name 
SET my_id_column= nextval('my_sequence_name');
```

PS: to continue from the current max ID, you would rather do

```
--Current max id:
SELECT setval(‘my_sequence_name’, max(my_id_column)) FROM my_table_name;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121045/discussion-on-answer-by-jgh-reset-restart-my-id-pk-field-on-a-table-in-postgresq).